# Leer el contenido de un archivo

Tags: java, archivo

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
       String directorio, fichero = "fichero1.txt";

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("introduce la ruta de la carpeta");
        directorio= lector.nextLine();

        crearFichero(directorio,fichero);
        verContenido(directorio);

    }
    public static void crearFichero(String directorio, String fichero) throws IOException {

        File f1=new File(directorio,fichero);
        if (!f1.exists()) {
                f1.createNewFile();
            }
    }
  public static void verContenido(String directorio) {
        try {
            FileReader entrada = new FileReader(directorio);

            int lee = entrada.read();

            while(lee!=-1) {
                lee=entrada.read();
                System.out.println(lee);
            }
            entrada.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No se ha encontrado ningun archivo");
        }
    }
```

Tengo que respetar las cabeceras de los metodos como estan, he tratado de leer el archivo con el metodo ver contenido pero siempre salta que no se encuentra el archivo. Como puedo hacer que me lea el fichero creado anteriormente, sin tener que cambiar las cabeceras de los metodos?( es decir void verContenido(String directorio) debe quedar asi no se puede cambiar ni añadir nada).

También tengo que añadir que se ven numeros cuando le digo que me lea el archivo, que diferencia hay para que en vez de numeros salga el texto que tengo guardado?
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
       String directorio, fichero = "fichero1.txt";

        Scanner lector = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.println("introduce la ruta de la carpeta");
        directorio= lector.nextLine();

        crearFichero(directorio,fichero);
        verContenido(directorio + "\\" + fichero );



    }
    public static void crearFichero(String directorio, String fichero) throws IOException {

        File f1=new File(directorio,fichero);
        if (!f1.exists()) {
                f1.createNewFile();
            }
    }
    public static void verContenido(String directorio) {
        try {
            FileReader entrada = new FileReader(directorio);
            System.out.println(directorio);
            int lee = entrada.read();

            while(lee!=-1) {
                lee=entrada.read();
                System.out.println(lee);
            }
            entrada.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No se ha encontrado ningun archivo");
        }
    }
```

Tienes que concatenar el directorio y el fichero, porque te dice que no tienes archivo porque estas leyendo el directorio y no el archivo.

Comment: No sabia que esto se pudiera hacer y fuera correcto Muchisimas gracias!!!!!

Comment: De nada  jajajaja

Comment: Gracias a ti tambien por tu respuesta :) basicamente eran la misma, disculpa que no te haya dado la tuya por buena pero no la entendia, esta era mucho mas clara. Igualmente Gracias

Comment: Tengo una pregunta mas que no ha sido resuelta, si en vez de numeros deseo ver letras, es decir el contenido como seria?

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo en ese codigo es que estas intentando leer el directorio y no el fichero en el procedimiento `verContenido()`.

Deberias de pasarle el fichero que creas en el metodo anterior por lo que deberias o pasarle como parametro: `verContenido(directorio+"//"+fichero);` o hacer ediciones en ese metodo.

Comment: No puedo hacer eso, el ejercicio me pide que el metodo sea ese, no se como hacerlo realmente asi, el contenido de el si puede cambiar solo se me daba la cabecera del metodo

Comment: El metodo es el mismo solo cambias el parametro que le pasas a la funcion en el main

Comment: Como seria eso? No te estoy entendiendo

Comment: Esq se me daba en el ejercicio esto: void verContenido(string directorio) y a partir de ahi debia crear yo el metodo

Comment: Actualmente en tu codigo en el Main tienes: "verContenido(directorio);". Sustituyelo por "verContenido(directorio+"//"+fichero);"